# How to use the reverse engineering (Entity Framework) on a 3.5 SQL Server Compact?

Tags: sql, .net, database, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I use the **Microsoft Sync Framework** (MSF) to synchronize my **SQL Server Compact 3.5** with my SQL Server (online).

I found out that **MSF** doesn't support **SQL Server Compact 4.0**, so i must use the **3.5**.

My problem is : In **Visual Studio 2012**, I can't find a way to perform a **reverse engineering** on a SQL Server Compact 3.5, only the 4.0 revision is proposed.

Is there a way to use the reverse engineering with a SQL Server Compact 3.5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NuGet:
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.Legacy

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.Legacy/

Comment: In addition, you must install the latest version of the SQL Server Compact Toolbox to get the required DDEX provider installed and also the EF 6.1 Tools